# Select WMI TargetInstance from multiple classes?

Tags: c++, winapi, wmi, wql

I am a `C++` programmer working in `VS2010`. Currently I am using `WMI` to monitor the processes and devices in the system. While writing `WQL` query, is it possible to select the `TargetInstance` from multiple classes? 
For example, instead of `select * from __InstanceOperationEvent within 1 where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PnPEntity'`, how can I use something like `select * from __InstanceOperationEvent within .1 where TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PnpEntity','Win32_DiskDrive'`.

I tried using `,` , `OR`, etc.But it failed.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was not a big deal!!!

`select * from __InstanceOperationEvent within 1 where (TargetInstance ISA Win32_PnPEntity') OR (TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_CDROMDRIVE')` solved my question.